# Term for a doorway without a door

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a specific term I could use in a floor plan for the doorway leading from one room to another? For example: a person is in the living room and looks through the "doorway" that leads into the kitchen. Obviously there is no door, but is this opening still referred to as a *doorway*?

Comment: It's acceptable to say "doorway" for a door frame with no door in it, or even a door-sized gap with no frame at all.

Comment: entrance is fine also, the word doesn't imply a door , and is used commonly ( google "Kitchen entrance" to see).

Comment: "Passageway" is a fairly generic term for such an opening.

Comment: I would say corridor could be a possible word depending on how long the doorway is

Comment: To me (as a Brit), "passageway" & "corridor" both imply that there is some *length* to the aperture; whereas I would expect a "doorway" to have no 'length' beyond the thickness of the wall in which it is an aperture.

Comment: Not sure if technically a dupe, as this exists - but on a different SE site: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16371/whats-a-doorway-that-doesnt-have-a-door-called

Comment: That is a definitive answer to this question and it also shows you how to draw both "cased" and "arched" openings on a set of plans.

Comment: Hobbit hole? People port?

Comment: What about door-away? :)

Answer (score 49):

**Doorway** would indeed be acceptable. Consider that, if the doorway has a door, you cannot see through to the other side unless the door is open. In this case, depending on your angle and the location of the door, it is perfectly possible that the door is entirely invisible. If so, its existence or non-existence is irrelevant to your perception of the doorway (or frame). So doorway is applicable regardless of the existence of a door.

Comment: I hate it when I leave my doo open.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - Me too.

Answer (score 26):

If it's curved it's an **archway**.

If it's entirely right angles it's a **trabeation**.

> *trabeated*: designed or constructed with horizontal beams or lintels –[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trabeated)

Credit to *The Sims 4*, calling some of them **[post-and-lintel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_and_lintel) entry frames** and describing one as *trabeated*.

Comment: I'd like to point out that I've never heard the word "trabeation" in colloquial English, and it's such a rare word that every spell check I have marks it as a typo.

Comment: I've never heard a complaint about calling a square archway an archway.

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced trabeation applies since it seems to refer more to ancient architecture involving stone columns. I could be wrong though.

Comment: It's rather obscure but it is specifically, "The use of beams in architectural construction, rather than arches or vaulting." –[OD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/trabeation)

Comment: @StarWeaver, let me fix that for you - I'll complain.  If there's no curves, it is _not_ an archway.  Ever.

Comment: I suspect that “arch” and “archway” are shifting in common usage to mean any such short-length passageway, regardless of curvature. For example, the [“holodeck arch”](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Holodeck) referred to repeatedly on the *Star Trek* TV series & movies. This usage seems natural and unnoticed even with some of the instances having a design that is nearly squared.

Answer (score 25):

You might consider ***entryway*** and [***entranceway***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/entranceway?s=t).

> entryway
>
> A passage for affording entrance.
>
> Word Origin: (1740-1750); Americanism; entry + way
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/entryway)
>
> *Peeking his head through the entryway, he saw a tiny figure hunched over a lathe in the dark interior of the room.* [The Temple of thé Wild Geese](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&biw=476&bih=313&tbm=bks&q=%22his+head+through+the+entryway%22&oq=%22his+head+through+the+entryway%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...27111.40931.0.41560.44.33.0.0.0.0.410.6042.0j8j10j4j2.24.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..24.10.2596.W5Go_-2wCp0)
>
> *This is an odd type of room—no windows at all—and no door in the entranceway—There must be a door. How did I get in here?* [Tumbleweeds: An Authentic Collection of Windblown Tales of Americana Caught in the Cross Hair](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Qf0eN12YuOAC&pg=PA278&lpg=PA278&dq=%22door+in+the+entranceway%22&source=bl&ots=Id8vxWkQq_&sig=phZdeylJLtvtMxRJyOUg1vi1Sso&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj78qSZ7YbMAhUHWSwKHX9mB6YQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22door%20in%20the%20entranceway%22&f=false)
>
> *There's no door in the entryway to the structure, and you suddenly understand that one is not necessary.* [What Lies Beneath the Clock Tower](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8XIchfIAJ6UC&pg=PT77&lpg=PT77&dq=%22no+door+in+the+entryway%22&source=bl&ots=U1mRGL3t-l&sig=cshnuO7RM8t_U3XjFf1rmhMo4Eg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje0JjB74bMAhXIESwKHZiMAvwQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22no%20door%20in%20the%20entryway%22&f=false)
>
> [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22entryway+leading+to+the+kitchen%22&prmd=isnv&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipzPvM4YbMAhUJ0hoKHcwuDhcQ_AUIDCgG&biw=512&bih=336)

Comment: But what if an "Exit Only" sign is hanging over it?!

Comment: What if it's a jar??

Comment: If it's a jar, clearly it isn't a door. ;)

Comment: @talrnu You wouldn't see that from the outside.

Comment: why not just entry or entrance?

Answer (score 14):

The technical term for this is:

**cased opening**

Definition:

*An interior doorway or opening with all the trim and molding installed, but without a door or closure.*

http://www.dictionaryofconstruction.com/definition/cased-opening.html

For an entrance between two rooms without the door trimmings, I would therefore suggest simply "**opening**".

Comment: Only if it's cased, otherwise it's just an opening.

Comment: Regardless, most people would refer to it just as an "opening". I think this is the best answer.

Comment: Following the comments, I've amended the answer to include simply "Opening".

Answer (score 13):

**portal**

> 1. A doorway, entrance, or gate, especially one that is large and imposing.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/portal

Comment: I wouldn't call the doorway between my kitchen and living room a "portal".

Comment: You might not, but that doesn't mean it isn't a word for it. I've often heard the term portal used when discussing the layout of houses, for more than just doorways (such as service hatches) @MaxWilliams

Comment: ...which isn't to say you're wrong, just that it's not a common usage of the word.

Comment: @MaxWilliams In a sense, it's literally the same word. "Portal" (from *porta* - door) is just Latin for "doorway".

Comment: @MaxWilliams I would, but the fact my kitchen and living room are in Aperture Science's underground complex might have something to do with that.

Comment: I agree that this is a potential word, but certainly not *commonly* used.

Comment: I think this word carries much more connotation of sci-fi e.g. to another dimension, these days

Comment: I think we basically agree: To answer the question *as posed in the title*, `portal` is appropriate for a large imposing passageway. For example, entrance ways into a mansion, or passageway between sections of a castle. Like [this](https://www.flickr.com/photos/atelier_tee/256872913/) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_of_Brandenburg-Ansbach-Kulmbach#/media/File:Portal_castle_legnica.JPG). For a more common scenario *as posed in the body of the question* between living room and kitchen, `portal` is not commonly used.

Comment: I really wonder how some of you lot on this site must speak at home - there are really some truly bizarre word suggestions that come out of this place.  `Be greeted to my commorancy, associate!  Please pursue me through the portal to the parlour where we may congregate in anticipation of our evening collation`.

Comment: @J... OP specifically said floor plan, hence the terms would be more formal and technical than in normal conversation.

Answer (score 4):

In the UK, estate agents' descriptions of property distinguish between a "doorway" (i.e. what the OP describes) and a "door". For example "**Entrance Hall** ... *doorways* to various rooms, *door* to:- **Guest Cloakroom** ..." (quote from http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/property-17919543.html) The photos in the link show that one of the "doorways" between two rooms has no door.

In a properly drawn floor plan it should obvious whether or not there is a door in a particular location, without any verbal description.

Answer (score 3):

I think that calling it a doorway is valid, for many of the good reasons that others have pointed out, however, it does also have to do with exactly what information you may or may not be trying to convey.

For instance, if you were describing an apartment to a prospective renter, they might be interested to know whether or not there are doors on the doorway; calling it a doorway does leave open the possibility that there *might* be doors. If you wanted to emphasize that there are no doors, then calling it an archway, or some other term, might be more precise.

Answer (score 2):

If it has all the trim and molding of a doorway, just there is no door, then you'd call that a cased opening:
http://www.dictionaryofconstruction.com/definition/cased-opening.html

But as others have said, we'd be getting too technical here. Doorway would still be understood and accepted everywhere but in the most snobbish or English circles.

Answer (score -2):

**Threshold** would also work here, I believe.  A threshold applies to an entrance with or without a door, though it refers to the division between one side and the other.

Comment: A [threshold](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/threshold) is the strip of wood/stone/metal/etc. affixed to the floor in the doorway. That is why we carry our bride over the threshold not through the threshold.

Comment: Downvoting because incorrect, Erik points out. Doubly inappropriate in an architectural context (what OP wants).

Comment: I'm in disagreement with the downvotes. I've found several dictionaries where the second or third entries state that a threshold is a doorway or entrance. Colloquially it is common to use that in its concrete as well as abstract sense, and I found no reference that stated that it only referred to the literal structure affixed to the floor and ended with that.